# SQL Update Bug (Value not updated after it said that it is)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, sql-update

I ran the following in my sql database:

```
update table1 SET car_color_code="red metalic" where car_model="335i";
```

and it said:

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec) Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1 
>   Warnings: 0

However, I dont see the change in the table
The table looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
| ID | model | manufacturer | car_color_code   |
|  1 | 335i  | BMW          | NULL             |
------------------------------------------------
```

So the null from before should be replaced with "red metalic" but it stays NULL.

However when i try to insert again it says:

> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

And when i try to select again I still dont see the change in car_color_code column...

My table description is

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| manufacturer     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| car_color_code   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Any triggers on the table?  This fits into the 'weird behavior' category

Comment: How are your columns not nullable but the default is `NULL`?

Comment: @Salman still NULL :'(

Comment: @AaronDietz ill fix it after but thats not the problem here

Comment: How many records do u have?
Can try the query over the other records?
can u delete the table and create a new one again?
But do the steps one by one

Comment: @Salman yeah after deleting the table and redoing everything it finally works

Comment: so, i would write an answer for u, and please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgot to `commit`. It is possible that you have exited out of MySQL server and tried the select statement after relogging in.

Make sure you `commit` after you update.